# Carry Look Ahead Adder for stabilize the sum

Tags: digital-circuits

An four-bit carry-look-ahead adder for computing the sum of 2 numbers
, where A and B are integers represented in 2's complement form. If the decimal value of A is 3, the decimal value of B that leads to the longest value for the sum to stabilize is __________________

I know adder is used for adding two numbers and carry look ahead adder is used for propagating the carry. But how it could be used for stabilising a sum, I couldn't understand this part and couldn't able to answer

Comment: "Stabilisation" is probably meaning waiting due to the propagation time across gates. Compared to cascading full adders, a carry look-ahead circuit allows to reduce the overall time of the multi-bit adder.

Comment: ok, can u discuss it more?